# Snapshot of drive

Tags: usb, backup, cloning, snapshot

Does technology exist which allows you to take an instantanious snapshot of a drive?

At the moment, I am using `dd` which takes a few minutes to create an image of a usb drive to my hdd.  Is it possible to somehow take a snapshot instead?

Not sure if this is technologically possible, but thought I should ask.

Comment: Take a look at this SU Q&A too: http://superuser.com/questions/314480/in-linux-how-do-i-create-restore-an-image-snapshot-of-my-entire-drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such technology exists, but it you would have to format your USB device either with ZFS file system, or use a LVM instead of normal partitioning. Both of these solutions are incompatible with Windows use, so you wouldn't be able to use your USB stick on Windows computers anymore.

Comment: Not being windows compatible is fine by me.  So which solution is quicker to implement ZFS or LVM?

Comment: LVM is better suited in this case. http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html tells you more about snapshots and backups.

Answer (score 1):

There are filesystems that have snapshot possibility (zfs or btrfs), but that doesn't copy any data at first. It creates a copy-on-write (lazy copy) on THE SAME drive.

So if you do want a copy on another drive, then `dd` is the most exact definition of a snapshot I can think of. Also, `dd` is loop-back mountable, so it IS your flash drive in every sense.

If you want incrementally updated dump on your hard drive, you could also use `rsync` to only copy files that were changed from the previous version.